# Media query error , Skeleton Framework

Tags: css, media-queries, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I have a problem in the css of Skeleton Framework . I downloaded it and edit it like the example , I added the large screen style `@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px)` but when I test it , it doesn't work.

here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/F4BmP/1324/)

Answer (score 0):

Is your viewport greater than 1280px? Media queries play nice for me.